# Play: With A Memorable Conversation between a villain and his henchman

Tags: identification-request, william-shakespeare

I remember reading several lines from what I think was a Shakespearean type play. It was between a villain and one of his henchman, and I think they were discussing the murder of someone referred to as “He”. The villain was trying to keep the conversation vague, and I think he was annoyed by the henchman, who referred to him as “My lord”. It seemed like it was by Shakespeare, but I did some searches and couldn’t find anything.

I know this is kind of a long shot due to the lack of information I have, because I only read a little excerpt of it, a while ago, but I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a scene from the Shakespeare play *King John*, in which the eponymous king commands his henchman Hubert to kill his nephew Arthur. There are two passages which might be what you're thinking of, although neither *exactly* fits since the king isn't completely vague about the topic. (I found these by searching [the full text](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/john/full.html) for "my lord".)

1. > HUBERT:    So well, that what you bid me undertake,
   >   Though that my death were adjunct to my act,
   >   By heaven, I would do it.
   >
   > KING JOHN:    Do not I know thou wouldst?
   >   Good Hubert, Hubert, Hubert, throw thine eye
   >   On yon young boy: I'll tell thee what, my friend,
   >   He is a very serpent in my way;
   >   And whereso'er this foot of mine doth tread,
   >   He lies before me: dost thou understand me?
   >   Thou art his keeper.
   >
   > HUBERT:    And I'll keep him so,
   >   That he shall not offend your majesty.
   >
   > KING JOHN:    Death.
   >
   > HUBERT:    My lord?
   >
   > KING JOHN:    A grave.
   >
   > HUBERT:    He shall not live.
   >
   > KING JOHN:    Enough.
   >   I could be merry now. Hubert, I love thee;
   >   Well, I'll not say what I intend for thee:
   >   Remember. Madam, fare you well:
   >   I'll send those powers o'er to your majesty.
2. > HUBERT:    My lord, they say five moons were seen to-night;
   >   Four fixed, and the fifth did whirl about
   >   The other four in wondrous motion.
   >
   > KING JOHN:    Five moons!
   >
   > HUBERT:    Old men and beldams in the streets
   >   Do prophesy upon it dangerously:
   >   Young Arthur's death is common in their mouths:
   >   And when they talk of him, they shake their heads
   >   And whisper one another in the ear;
   >   And he that speaks doth gripe the hearer's wrist,
   >   Whilst he that hears makes fearful action,
   >   With wrinkled brows, with nods, with rolling eyes.
   >   I saw a smith stand with his hammer, thus,
   >   The whilst his iron did on the anvil cool,
   >   With open mouth swallowing a tailor's news;
   >   Who, with his shears and measure in his hand,
   >   Standing on slippers, which his nimble haste
   >   Had falsely thrust upon contrary feet,
   >   Told of a many thousand warlike French
   >   That were embattailed and rank'd in Kent:
   >   Another lean unwash'd artificer
   >   Cuts off his tale and talks of Arthur's death.
   >
   > KING JOHN:    Why seek'st thou to possess me with these fears?
   >   Why urgest thou so oft young Arthur's death?
   >   Thy hand hath murder'd him: I had a mighty cause
   >   To wish him dead, but thou hadst none to kill him.
   >
   > HUBERT:    No had, my lord! why, did you not provoke me?
   >
   > KING JOHN:    It is the curse of kings to be attended
   >   By slaves that take their humours for a warrant
   >   To break within the bloody house of life,
   >   And on the winking of authority
   >   To understand a law, to know the meaning
   >   Of dangerous majesty, when perchance it frowns
   >   More upon humour than advised respect.
   >
   > HUBERT:    Here is your hand and seal for what I did.
   >
   > KING JOHN:    O, when the last account 'twixt heaven and earth
   >   Is to be made, then shall this hand and seal
   >   Witness against us to damnation!
   >   How oft the sight of means to do ill deeds
   >   Make deeds ill done! Hadst not thou been by,
   >   A fellow by the hand of nature mark'd,
   >   Quoted and sign'd to do a deed of shame,
   >   This murder had not come into my mind:
   >   But taking note of thy abhorr'd aspect,
   >   Finding thee fit for bloody villany,
   >   Apt, liable to be employ'd in danger,
   >   I faintly broke with thee of Arthur's death;
   >   And thou, to be endeared to a king,
   >   Made it no conscience to destroy a prince.
   >
   > HUBERT:    My lord--
   >
   > KING JOHN:    Hadst thou but shook thy head or made a pause
   >   When I spake darkly what I purposed,
   >   Or turn'd an eye of doubt upon my face,
   >   As bid me tell my tale in express words,
   >   Deep shame had struck me dumb, made me break off,
   >   And those thy fears might have wrought fears in me:
   >   But thou didst understand me by my signs
   >   And didst in signs again parley with sin;
   >   Yea, without stop, didst let thy heart consent,
   >   And consequently thy rude hand to act
   >   The deed, which both our tongues held vile to name.
   >   Out of my sight, and never see me more!
   >   My nobles leave me; and my state is braved,
   >   Even at my gates, with ranks of foreign powers:
   >   Nay, in the body of this fleshly land,
   >   This kingdom, this confine of blood and breath,
   >   Hostility and civil tumult reigns
   >   Between my conscience and my cousin's death.

Or it could be the very last scene from the Shakespeare play *Richard II*, in which the new king Henry IV (Bolingbroke) rebukes his follower Exton for murdering the old king Richard II in prison.

3. > EXTON:    Great king, within this coffin I present
   >   Thy buried fear: herein all breathless lies
   >   The mightiest of thy greatest enemies,
   >   Richard of Bordeaux, by me hither brought.
   >
   > HENRY BOLINGBROKE:    Exton, I thank thee not; for thou hast wrought
   >   A deed of slander with thy fatal hand
   >   Upon my head and all this famous land.
   >
   > EXTON:    From your own mouth, my lord, did I this deed.
   >
   > HENRY BOLINGBROKE:    They love not poison that do poison need,
   >   Nor do I thee: though I did wish him dead,
   >   I hate the murderer, love him murdered.
   >   The guilt of conscience take thou for thy labour,
   >   But neither my good word nor princely favour:
   >   With Cain go wander through shades of night,
   >   And never show thy head by day nor light.
   >   Lords, I protest, my soul is full of woe,
   >   That blood should sprinkle me to make me grow:
   >   Come, mourn with me for that I do lament,
   >   And put on sullen black incontinent:
   >   I'll make a voyage to the Holy Land,
   >   To wash this blood off from my guilty hand:
   >   March sadly after; grace my mournings here;
   >   In weeping after this untimely bier.

If none of these are right, then a useful tool to search for a better match is [Open Source Shakespeare](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/search/search-advanced.php), where you can perform an advanced search on the full texts of all Shakespeare's plays. (I tried searching for the exact phrases `my lord` and `he` and `his`, in History and Tragedy plays only, and got 97 results none of which matched your description. If you can remember *any* more exact phrases from the passage you're looking for, it would be really helpful.) *King John* just came to mind because one of the major plot points in it is a villain commanding a henchman to kill another character, and similarly *Richard II*.

Comment: Thanks, it was King John. I own Richard II and checked a while ago, but that wasn't it. The only lines I remembered were the "Death. My lord. A grave" part